# Vue - default values of nested properties

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How can I set a default value of a nested property of a Object `prop`?

Apparently, Vue parse default value of nested properties only if the first level Object `prop` is `undefined`.

Example:

```
Vue.component('example', {
  props: {
    options: {
       type: Object,
       default: function() {
          return {
             nested: {
                type: Object,
                default: function(){
                   return 'default value'
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Apparently, Vue parse default value of nested properties only if the
>   fist level Object prop is not undefined.

Yes and it makes sense because if you don't have outer object, you won't be able to have inner or nested properties.

So I think it's even more readable just set as default `{}` an emtpy object for the first level object and you should make your own defensive validations against **undefined** or **null**, like the bellow example:

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      option: {
        type: Object,
        default: () => {},
        required: false
      }
    },
    computed: {
      optionReceived: function () {
        const defaultNestedValue = 'Some default value'
        const option = this.option.nested || defaultNestedValue;
        return option;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: **EDIT**: Apparently, Vue parse default value of nested properties only if the first level Object prop **is** undefined. (sorry for the typo)

Comment: In my example, if the first level object is undefined:
`<example><example>`
The value of `options.nested` is set to default.
But passing a partial `option` prop:
let options = {}
`<example :options=options><example>`
The partial options object is not merged with default value of nested properties.

Comment: I managed to resolve this defining computed properties, that returns this.options.nested or the default value. But i'm not sure that's the best approach.

Comment: @DaniloSampaio usign computed properties is a good approach if the property change it's value on the parent it will update the property in the child component. Regarding why when you are passing an empty object `{}` to the component and is not setting the `default value` is because an empty object is a truthy value. Take a look to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy

Comment: Is there any reason why Vue doesn't merge the passed object with the default value of the nested properties? Performance, simplicity, etc.

Comment: It's not Vuejs, it's the way a truthy evaluation works, if you try to make a conditional evaluation of empty object `if ({}) {console.log('Is {} it true?, Yes it is')}`  it will print `Is {} it true?, Yes it is`. The same case happens when you pass an empty object to a component in Vuejs, since it will never evaluates an empty object as a false it won't assign the default value. In the other hand `undefined` it is a falsy value so that's why it assigns the default, I hope this explanation help you @DaniloSampaio

Comment: Ok, could you edit your example to use computed property, instead of created hook?

Comment: Great, the example has been updated using computed properties @DaniloSampaio

Comment: Since the option has a default value {}, it's not necessary check `this.option && this.option.nested`, just return `this.option.nested || defaultNestedValue`

Answer (score 2):

I think it is always better to make your data structure easy to use and as flat as possible. Because nested props in Vue is never a good choice.

Assume the `options` you mentioned in your Vue component have a lot of properties inside.

Example:

```
props: {
  options: {
    bookAttributes: {
      colorAttributes: { coverColor:   'red', ribbonColor: 'green' },
      sizeAttributes: { coverSize: 10, ribbonSize: 2 },
      ... 
    }
  }
}
```

you could make them flat like this for better comprehension.

```
props: {
    coverSize: 10,
    coverColor: 'red',
    ribbonColor: 'green,
    ribbonSize: 2 ...
}
```

And then you and your colleagues could happily use your component like this:

```
<your-component>
    coverSize="15"
    coverColor="blue"
    ribbonColor="red"
    ribbonSize="3"
</your-component>
```

Good luck and wish you well.

Comment: For a simple option object, it works fine. But when i have a complex component, a flat prop object might be too verbose:
<your-component>
   childCompCoverSize="15"
</your-component>

Comment: If your component is complex, simply break it down into small components. "Parent-Children" model should provide you convenience on passing props.